# GridBagLayout: panels extend over other panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create a UI with the following panel layout:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jrYUxRO.jpg]

However, when I populate the white panel with images (that are on JLabels) the following occurs:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3ECRndH.jpg]

Would the problem be that the images themselves do not resize to cause the panel to "fit"? If so, is there an easy to resize them, or am I going to have to find the size the GridBag assigns to it and then scale each image according to that?

EDIT: What I am trying to do here is to keep panel 1 (white) the same size as in the first picture when I actually add my images. **I do not want the panel to resize and take over some of the other panels.**

```
    GridBagLayout gb = new GridBagLayout();
    gb.columnWeights = new double[] {0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25};
    gb.rowWeights = new double[] {0.5,0.5};
    setLayout(gb);
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.gridwidth = 3;
    add(new WhitePanel(), gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(new RedPanel(), gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(new GreenPanel(), gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.gridwidth = 2;
    add(new BluePanel(), gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.gridwidth = 1;
    add(new YellowPanel(), gc);
```

The following is my WhitePanel constructor:

```
    public WhitePanel()
    {
        setBackground(new Color(1f,1f,1f,1f));

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        for (int type = 0; type < 4; type++)
        {
            for (int tier = 0; tier < 7; tier++)
            {
                gems[type][tier] = new D3Gem(type, tier, 0);
                add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(gems[type][tier].getImage())),gc);
                gc.gridx++;
            }
            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy++;
        }
    }
```

EDIT EDIT: I was hoping for the white panel to remain the same size and for the JLabels themselves to resize (i.e. have the white space between labels to shrink) to fit that panel.

Note: If I do not have the line `gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;`, then the images on the white panel only take up a small portion of the white panel (just enough so that they don't overlap). As a result, I assumed that `gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;` would perfectly fill the white panel.

"SOLUTION" EDIT: Alright, I seem to have a solution albeit a shaky one. I simply appended  `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,1));` to the white panel's constructor and as a result it stayed the size I wanted it to. If anyone would care to elaborate what is going on I would appreciate it :)

Comment: This is how GridBagLayout works -- it tries to use the preferredSizes of your components to fit them in the best possible way and size. Consider 1) showing pertinent code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org), and 2) showing what you would like the lower gui to look like when it holds all images.

Comment: `"What I am trying to do here is to keep panel 1 (white) the same size as in the first picture when I actually add my images. I do not want the panel to resize and take over some of the other panels."` -- so what behavior do you want to occur when the images take up more size than the component shows? Do you want some of the images to not be shown? Please give us as much information as possible to allow us to understand the problem.

Comment: Edited again above, sorry for the lack of info.

Comment: If anyone is willing to explain to me what is going on, please read from EDIT EDIT downwards, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `ipadx` for the red (or yellow) panel's `GridBagConstraint`

From javadoc

```
/**
 * This field specifies the internal padding of the component, how much
 * space to add to the minimum width of the component. The width of
 * the component is at least its minimum width plus
 * <code>ipadx</code> pixels.
 * <p>
 * The default value is <code>0</code>.
 * @serial
 * @see #clone()
 * @see java.awt.GridBagConstraints#ipady
 */
public int ipadx;
```

Comment: I'm rather new to GridBagLayout, so forgive me for making false assumptions here, but surely GridBagLayout reserves a certain space for my components to be placed within the white panel? Why would adding images to the panel cause it to expand? I checked what it was doing and seems as though it was adding blank space between each of the JLabels on the white panel. Is there a way to reduce this space?

Comment: images added - preferre size changed - layout adapts children to hmmm comfort their pref sizes